# Php mail function table on right

Tags: php, sendmail

I have tried several diffrent codes to have php send the form and have the mail alighned on right, and nothnig works.  When I open the mail, it is always on left

```
<?php
$to = "skatz25@hotmail.com";
$subject = "טופס הפניית מתנדב/ גוף פונה";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 

$rname = $_POST['rname'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$refrence = $_POST['refrence'];

$msg = '
<html>        
   <body dir="rtl">
      <table dir="rtl" style="direction:rtl">
         <tr>
           <td style="text-align: right;">מקבל הפנייה:</td>
           <td>' . $rname . '</td>
          <tr>
        </table>
   </body>
<html>
';


mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
?>
```

When I open the mail in hotmail the text is rtl but starts from the left side of the page instead of the right

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I tried the suggestion of adding a table within a table with the width 100% as below, but when I open the email, the text is still on left side of page.  Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must draw a table that has width and heigth set to 100% and in that table, create another table, aligned to the right, like: `<table width='100%' height='100%'><tr><td align='right'> <table align='right'><tr><td>content</td></tr></table> </td></tr></table>`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a width to the table.

Comment: when trying to send it in a mail, it wont work; you have to have a container for the second table